# Regex not matching values

Tags: python, regex

So I am creating a program which reads input Strings, and sees if they contains codes within a list.  I am attempting to use a regex to get the matching string, but am having a bit of a problem with my regex.  Here is my code for reference:

```
import re

values = ["T1245F8", "T1267F8", "T1234F8"]

checkVals = ["rfgT12B45F8asd", "b65dT12B67F8lgkt", "4fgy7tgT12B34F8", "fgtrfT12B94F8fkg"]

for i in range(len(checkVals)):
    match = False
    parsedVal = re.match('T12B[0-9]{2}F8', checkVals[i])
    for j in range(len(values)):
        if parsedVal == values[j]:
            match = True
    print(match)
```

The output I am expecting if 3 `True` and 1 `False` statement printed out.  However instead of get 4 `False` statements.

EDIT: Fixed a typo in my regex, but it still isn't working.

Comment: `re.match` anchors the search to the start of the string and the `$` is your regex is anchoring to the end... so you're only going to match strings that are identical to the pattern... use `re.search` and remove the `$` and it should work (once you add in the `B` in the text your pattern will fail on...)

Comment: You could write this as: `matches = [val for val in checkVals if re.search(r'T12B\d{2}F8', val)]`... (which matches all 4 - so not sure which one you're expecting to not match...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be just a typo in your question post but i think you meant:

```
values = ["T12B45F8", "T12B67F8", "T12B34F8"]
```

then, just change this line:

```
parsedVal = re.match('T12B[0-9]{2}F8', checkVals[i])
```

to this one:

```
parsedVal = re.search('T12B[0-9]{2}F8', checkVals[i]).group()
```

this will give you the actual parts you're matching.

output:

```
True
True
True
False
```

as a conclusion, the entire code should look like this:

```
import re

values = ["T12B45F8", "T12B67F8", "T12B34F8"]

checkVals = ["rfgT12B45F8asd", "b65dT12B67F8lgkt", "4fgy7tgT12B34F8", "fgtrfT12B94F8fkg"]

for i in range(len(checkVals)):
    match = False
    parsedVal = re.search('T12B[0-9]{2}F8', checkVals[i]).group()
    for j in range(len(values)):
        if parsedVal == values[j]:
            match = True
    print(match)
```

I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It's working as intended now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is 2 problems

### First:

The `$` at the end of the regex is not allowing any characters after

### Second:

Should be searching for `T12B` not `T12`

*It is also possible you made a type while entering your test data. For example `rfgT12B45F8asd` will not match your current expression because it contains `T12B` as a prefix to your numbers not `T12`

### Final Regex:

`T12B[0-9]{2}F8`

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was a bad typo on my end.  However I made that change to the regex and I am still only getting False values for my output.

Comment: @Skitzafreak I think `parsedVal` should be a `boolean` value depending on if the regex found a match. Use that to check if there was a match.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `$` from your regexp, it matches at the end of string, while your strings don't end in `F8`. Also, use `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Comment: Made a quick change to my code as per your suggestion, still getting all False results.  My Regex was changed to `T12B[0-9]{2}F8` and i changed `re.match` to re.search`